# Any pre-trained ML models or classifiers for finding a tweet's sentiment?

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I wonder are there any existing/pre trained ML models or trained classifiers for finding a tweet's sentiment.

I came across Twitter samples in `Python NLTK` library at http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/. This dataset is useful for classifying a Tweet to be either a positive or a negative. But I'm looking for a pre-trained ML model for finding DOW/Fintech companies Twitter sentiment which can predict the TextBlob's polarity and subjectivity of tweets.

IMO, a domain specific pre-trained ML model would yield better results. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How have the answers you found with Google been lacking? This just feels like such an obviously self-solvable problem, it doesn't seem a good fit for here (and certainly not in the way asked it)

Comment: Neil, I mentioned in the question that I found Tweet samples from Python NLTK library with just positive or negative labels, I want a score rather than just a label.
As you said, it may be a self solvable problem, but following the software engineering principle -- "Do not reinvent the Wheel", I posted this question.

Comment: I didn't mean that you needed to write a solution, merely that with your understanding of what you want, you'd be able to find the answer with Google. The whole "TextBlob's polarity and subjectivity"-part feels confused. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look here:
http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task5/

This is the website of SemEval Task 5 from 2017, which is kind of an academic competition in NLP, for classifying financial sentiment tasks. Reading the accompanying summarization of the results (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S17-2089), it seems that a hybrid approach using machine learning with a financial-lexicon-based approach yields the best results. This also suggests that you probably need a model that is specific to the financial domain.

You likely would have to train the model yourself though, which doesn't seem too hard as 42% of the participants in the competition using sci-kit learn.